# Support libraries are not imported

Tags: java, android

I can’t import the support library, now I’ll import only:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
```

Googling, I realized that androidx. replaces support. But still the question is open.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.criminalintent"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

need to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
dependencies {
... //other 
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
}
```

Use AndroidX instead of Support Library.